# gdb Does not stop at the breakpoint in "wxWidget" Demo Code

Tags: gdb, wxwidgets, vscode-debugger

I have started working with `[wxWidget][1]` library recently. I am trying to use the gdb debugger with it however it does not stop at the breakpoints and exits the code.

I have checked my gdb configuration with sample code without wxWidget library and it works fine.

My Compilation command is

```
g++ -g -o ./main.exe ./main.cpp -IC:/Users/mypc/Desktop/WxLibs/include -IC:/Users/mypc/Desktop/WxLibs/lib/gcc810_x64_dll/mswud -LC:/Users/mypc/Desktop/WxLibs/lib/gcc810_x64_dll -l wxbase32ud -l wxmsw32ud_core -mwindows
```

I am adding the breakpoint in main.cpp at this line

```
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
->    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

My gdb commands and output are :

```
(gdb) break .\main.cpp:98
(gdb) run
Starting program: path\main.exe 
[New Thread 21848.0x4e88]
[New Thread 21848.0x3578]
[New Thread 21848.0x2bc8]
[New Thread 21848.0x6a08]
[Thread 21848.0x3578 exited with code 3221225781]
[Thread 21848.0x6a08 exited with code 3221225781]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

I was going through debugging [documentation given on wxWidget](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__debug.html#ga30ad68c25d4f7a731f60eb07419c2960) but could not infer much information. What is the reason gdb is not working with this library? Is it the library itself or I should look into another direction? Any simplified demo or explanation provided would be very helpful.

Comment: Error code `0xc0000135` means `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`, so your program couldn't even be started correctly because some dll is missing. Try calling your executable directly, it should tell you which dll(s).

Comment: @PJL, how exactly did you build wxwidgets?

Comment: @Igor I am using gcc compiled binary from wxwidget given on this link . https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/

Comment: @PJL, what you should do is to copy them into the directory where your executable is residing. Start with just bade and core ones.